# Create class in python

Tags: python

```
class Dlist(list):


    def append(self, val):
        super(Dlist, self).append(val)
        self.sort()

if __name__=='__main__':
    foo = Dlist([1,2,3,4,5])
    foo.append(6)
    foo/2
    print foo

I need [0.5, 1...]
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dlist' and 'int'

Comment: Tell us what's wrong with what you've got.

Comment: "i need that my foo/2 returns a list from this numbers" - what are you talking about?

Comment: nothing this is work but i need when i "foo"/2 return [0.5, 1, 1.5....]

Comment: how i can do this?thanks

Comment: Are you asking for a division operation on the list to return a new list where each element is divided by the divisor? What is `CommentList` and is it important to the question or can it be removed?

Comment: yes .ooy sorry CommentList==Dlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
divided_list = [float(x)/2 for x in foo]
```

This divides each value in a list by 2.

```
def divide_list(foo, divisor):
    return [float(x)/divisor for x in foo]
```

Where divisor is the number you want to divide by.

Comment: almost...but when i create "foo"  
it must divide what I want ...not only on 2

Comment: In that case divide by a variable instead of 2 :)

Comment: that when divided by the number should return a list of the items divided by that number:

Comment: for exemple:
>>>foo = Dlist([2, 4, 6])
>>>foo.append(8)
>>>foo.append(10)
>>>foo
>>>[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>>foo/2
>>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: not working( but thank you